# Customizing summary section of TestNG emailable report

Tags: testing, report, testng

TestNG generates an emailable report. I have seen that this report can be customized by using Listeners. But could not get what i wanted. My requirement is to include extra details in the summary section of this report. I want to be able to add may be a new table or extra columns to show the environment details of the test execution.

Trying to attach a screenshot but apparently missing something and it does not come up.

[image]

Comment: I use TestNG 6.8.7 and run my WebDriver tests with Maven. I wrote a custom listener that overrides onTestFailure() and calls Reporter.log() that puts a hyperlink to the screenshot to TestNG report (index.html). But it does not work for emailable-report.html. Is customizing emailable report the only way to go for attaching screenshots to this report?

Comment: The report just displays the HTML markup as is. It does not render it as link on emailable-report.html    <a href="file:///Users/harini/Documents/workspace/rql_qa/UI2.0/WikiApps/target/surefire-reports/screenshots/02-05-2014/TimerFormTest.testTimerInForm14:05:24.png"><img src="file:///Users/harini/Documents/workspace/rql_qa/UI2.0/WikiApps/target/surefire-reports/screenshots/02-05-2014/TimerFormTest.testTimerInForm14:05:24.png" alt="" height='400' width='500' />. But the link and screenshot are displayed correctly on index.html.

Comment: I think you should try the way it is mentioned in the above link? It works for me.

Comment: Here is [a fully working example I made](http://djangofan.github.io/testng-custom-report-example/) but I have since switched to using ReportNG.

Comment: @Harini Were you able to produce clickable links in the emailable report or did you end up customizing it yourself?

Comment: @Cagy79 I could not. The links worked in index.html but not in the emailable report. So we decided to use an alternate way of test reporting using our own Application Under Test.

Comment: Refer this latest link - http://www.testautomationsimplified.in#emailable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is what I have on my framework. I'll try to explain it (sorry my English)

Copy ReporterListenerAdapter.java and rename as MyReporterListenerAdapter.java, put it on your java project (/listener folder for example)

```
public class MyReporterListenerAdapter implements IReporter {

public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xml, List<ISuite> suites, String outdir) {}
}
```

Next, copy ReporterListener.java and rename as MyReporterListener.java

Too much code to paste here, but on *createWriter* function change the report name. For example: "emailable-MyFramework-report".

MyReporterListener.java

```
public class MyReporterListener extends MyReporterListenerAdapter {

    private static final Logger L = Logger.getLogger(MyReporterListener.class);

    // ~ Instance fields ------------------------------------------------------

    private PrintWriter m_out;

    private int m_row;

    private Integer m_testIndex;

    private int m_methodIndex;

    private Scanner scanner;

    // ~ Methods --------------------------------------------------------------

    /** Creates summary of the run */
    @Override
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xml, List<ISuite> suites,
            String outdir) {
        try {
            m_out = createWriter(outdir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.error("output file", e);
            return;
        }

        startHtml(m_out);
        generateSuiteSummaryReport(suites);
        generateMethodSummaryReport(suites);
        generateMethodDetailReport(suites);
        endHtml(m_out);
        m_out.flush();
        m_out.close();
    }

    protected PrintWriter createWriter(String outdir) throws IOException {
        java.util.Date now = new Date();
        new File(outdir).mkdirs();
        return new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                outdir, "emailable-FON-report"
                        + DateFunctions.dateToDayAndTimeForFileName(now)
                        + ".html"))));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a table showing the highlights of each test method with links to
     * the method details
     */
    protected void generateMethodSummaryReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
        m_methodIndex = 0;
        startResultSummaryTable("methodOverview");
        int testIndex = 1;
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            if (suites.size() > 1) {
                titleRow(suite.getName(), 5);
            }
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults();
            for (ISuiteResult r2 : r.values()) {
                ITestContext testContext = r2.getTestContext();
                String testName = testContext.getName();
                m_testIndex = testIndex;
                resultSummary(suite, testContext.getFailedConfigurations(),
                        testName, "failed", " (configuration methods)");
                resultSummary(suite, testContext.getFailedTests(), testName,
                        "failed", "");
                resultSummary(suite, testContext.getSkippedConfigurations(),
                        testName, "skipped", " (configuration methods)");
                resultSummary(suite, testContext.getSkippedTests(), testName,
                        "skipped", "");
                resultSummary(suite, testContext.getPassedTests(), testName,
                        "passed", "");
                testIndex++;
            }
        }
        m_out.println("</table>");
    }

    /** Creates a section showing known results for each method */
    protected void generateMethodDetailReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
        m_methodIndex = 0;
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults();
            for (ISuiteResult r2 : r.values()) {
                ITestContext testContext = r2.getTestContext();
                if (r.values().size() > 0) {
                    m_out.println("<h1>" + testContext.getName() + "</h1>");
                }
                resultDetail(testContext.getFailedConfigurations());
                resultDetail(testContext.getFailedTests());
                resultDetail(testContext.getSkippedConfigurations());
                resultDetail(testContext.getSkippedTests());
                resultDetail(testContext.getPassedTests());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param tests
     */
    private void resultSummary(ISuite suite, IResultMap tests, String testname,
            String style, String details) {
        if (tests.getAllResults().size() > 0) {
            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
            String lastClassName = "";
            int mq = 0;
            int cq = 0;
            for (ITestNGMethod method : getMethodSet(tests, suite)) {
                m_row += 1;
                m_methodIndex += 1;
                ITestClass testClass = method.getTestClass();
                String className = testClass.getName();
                if (mq == 0) {
                    String id = (m_testIndex == null ? null : "t"
                            + Integer.toString(m_testIndex));
                    titleRow(testname + " &#8212; " + style + details, 5, id);
                    m_testIndex = null;
                }
                if (!className.equalsIgnoreCase(lastClassName)) {
                    if (mq > 0) {
                        cq += 1;
                        m_out.print("<tr class=\"" + style
                                + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd") + "\">"
                                + "<td");
                        if (mq > 1) {
                            m_out.print(" rowspan=\"" + mq + "\"");
                        }
                        m_out.println(">" + lastClassName + "</td>" + buff);
                    }
                    mq = 0;
                    buff.setLength(0);
                    lastClassName = className;
                }
                Set<ITestResult> resultSet = tests.getResults(method);
                long end = Long.MIN_VALUE;
                long start = Long.MAX_VALUE;
                for (ITestResult testResult : tests.getResults(method)) {
                    if (testResult.getEndMillis() > end) {
                        end = testResult.getEndMillis();
                    }
                    if (testResult.getStartMillis() < start) {
                        start = testResult.getStartMillis();
                    }
                }
                mq += 1;
                if (mq > 1) {
                    buff.append("<tr class=\"" + style
                            + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "odd" : "even") + "\">");
                }
                String description = method.getDescription();
                String testInstanceName = resultSet
                        .toArray(new ITestResult[] {})[0].getTestName();
                buff.append("<td><a href=\"#m"
                        + m_methodIndex
                        + "\">"
                        + qualifiedName(method)
                        + " "
                        + (description != null && description.length() > 0 ? "(\""
                                + description + "\")"
                                : "")
                        + "</a>"
                        + (null == testInstanceName ? "" : "<br>("
                                + testInstanceName + ")") + "</td>"
                        + "<td class=\"numi\">" + resultSet.size() + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + start + "</td>" + "<td class=\"numi\">"
                        + (end - start) + "</td>" + "</tr>");
            }
            if (mq > 0) {
                cq += 1;
                m_out.print("<tr class=\"" + style
                        + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd") + "\">" + "<td");
                if (mq > 1) {
                    m_out.print(" rowspan=\"" + mq + "\"");
                }
                m_out.println(">" + lastClassName + "</td>" + buff);
            }
        }
    }

    /** Starts and defines columns result summary table */
    private void startResultSummaryTable(String style) {
        tableStart(style, "summary");
        m_out.println("<tr><th>Class</th>"
                + "<th>Method</th><th># of<br/>Scenarios</th><th>Start</th><th>Time<br/>(ms)</th></tr>");
        m_row = 0;
    }

    private String qualifiedName(ITestNGMethod method) {
        StringBuilder addon = new StringBuilder();
        String[] groups = method.getGroups();
        int length = groups.length;
        if (length > 0 && !"basic".equalsIgnoreCase(groups[0])) {
            addon.append("(");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    addon.append(", ");
                }
                addon.append(groups[i]);
            }
            addon.append(")");
        }

        return "<b>" + method.getMethodName() + "</b> " + addon;
    }

    private void resultDetail(IResultMap tests) {
        for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
            ITestNGMethod method = result.getMethod();
            m_methodIndex++;
            String cname = method.getTestClass().getName();
            m_out.println("<h2 id=\"m" + m_methodIndex + "\">" + cname + ":"
                    + method.getMethodName() + "</h2>");
            Set<ITestResult> resultSet = tests.getResults(method);
            generateForResult(result, method, resultSet.size());
            m_out.println("<p class=\"totop\"><a href=\"#summary\">back to summary</a></p>");

        }
    }

    /**
     * Write the first line of the stack trace
     * 
     * @param tests
     */
    private void getShortException(IResultMap tests) {

        for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
            m_methodIndex++;
            Throwable exception = result.getThrowable();
            List<String> msgs = Reporter.getOutput(result);
            boolean hasReporterOutput = msgs.size() > 0;
            boolean hasThrowable = exception != null;
            if (hasThrowable) {
                boolean wantsMinimalOutput = result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS;
                if (hasReporterOutput) {
                    m_out.print("<h3>"
                            + (wantsMinimalOutput ? "Expected Exception"
                                    : "Failure") + "</h3>");
                }

                // Getting first line of the stack trace
                String str = Utils.stackTrace(exception, true)[0];
                scanner = new Scanner(str);
                String firstLine = scanner.nextLine();
                m_out.println(firstLine);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write all parameters
     * 
     * @param tests
     */
    private void getParameters(IResultMap tests) {

        for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
            m_methodIndex++;
            Object[] parameters = result.getParameters();
            boolean hasParameters = parameters != null && parameters.length > 0;
            if (hasParameters) {

                for (Object p : parameters) {
                    m_out.println(Utils.escapeHtml(Utils.toString(p)) + " | ");
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void generateForResult(ITestResult ans, ITestNGMethod method,
            int resultSetSize) {
        Object[] parameters = ans.getParameters();
        boolean hasParameters = parameters != null && parameters.length > 0;
        if (hasParameters) {
            tableStart("result", null);
            m_out.print("<tr class=\"param\">");
            for (int x = 1; x <= parameters.length; x++) {
                m_out.print("<th>Param." + x + "</th>");
            }
            m_out.println("</tr>");
            m_out.print("<tr class=\"param stripe\">");
            for (Object p : parameters) {
                m_out.println("<td>" + Utils.escapeHtml(Utils.toString(p))
                        + "</td>");
            }
            m_out.println("</tr>");
        }
        List<String> msgs = Reporter.getOutput(ans);
        boolean hasReporterOutput = msgs.size() > 0;
        Throwable exception = ans.getThrowable();
        boolean hasThrowable = exception != null;
        if (hasReporterOutput || hasThrowable) {
            if (hasParameters) {
                m_out.print("<tr><td");
                if (parameters.length > 1) {
                    m_out.print(" colspan=\"" + parameters.length + "\"");
                }
                m_out.println(">");
            } else {
                m_out.println("<div>");
            }
            if (hasReporterOutput) {
                if (hasThrowable) {
                    m_out.println("<h3>Test Messages</h3>");
                }
                for (String line : msgs) {
                    m_out.println(line + "<br/>");
                }
            }
            if (hasThrowable) {
                boolean wantsMinimalOutput = ans.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS;
                if (hasReporterOutput) {
                    m_out.println("<h3>"
                            + (wantsMinimalOutput ? "Expected Exception"
                                    : "Failure") + "</h3>");
                }
                generateExceptionReport(exception, method);
            }
            if (hasParameters) {
                m_out.println("</td></tr>");
            } else {
                m_out.println("</div>");
            }
        }
        if (hasParameters) {
            m_out.println("</table>");
        }
    }

    protected void generateExceptionReport(Throwable exception,
            ITestNGMethod method) {
        m_out.print("<div class=\"stacktrace\">");
        m_out.print(Utils.stackTrace(exception, true)[0]);
        m_out.println("</div>");
    }

    /**
     * Since the methods will be sorted chronologically, we want to return the
     * ITestNGMethod from the invoked methods.
     */
    private Collection<ITestNGMethod> getMethodSet(IResultMap tests,
            ISuite suite) {
        List<IInvokedMethod> r = Lists.newArrayList();
        List<IInvokedMethod> invokedMethods = suite.getAllInvokedMethods();
        for (IInvokedMethod im : invokedMethods) {
            if (tests.getAllMethods().contains(im.getTestMethod())) {
                r.add(im);
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(r.toArray(new IInvokedMethod[r.size()]), new TestSorter());
        List<ITestNGMethod> result = Lists.newArrayList();

        // Add all the invoked methods
        for (IInvokedMethod m : r) {
            result.add(m.getTestMethod());
        }

        // Add all the methods that weren't invoked (e.g. skipped) that we
        // haven't added yet
        for (ITestNGMethod m : tests.getAllMethods()) {
            if (!result.contains(m)) {
                result.add(m);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void generateSuiteSummaryReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
        tableStart("testOverview", null);
        m_out.print("<tr>");
        tableColumnStart("Test");
        tableColumnStart("Methods<br/>Passed");
        tableColumnStart("Scenarios<br/>Passed");
        tableColumnStart("# skipped");
        tableColumnStart("# failed");
        tableColumnStart("Error messages");
        tableColumnStart("Parameters");
        tableColumnStart("Start<br/>Time");
        tableColumnStart("End<br/>Time");
        tableColumnStart("Total<br/>Time");
        tableColumnStart("Included<br/>Groups");
        tableColumnStart("Excluded<br/>Groups");

        m_out.println("</tr>");
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
        int qty_tests = 0;
        int qty_pass_m = 0;
        int qty_pass_s = 0;
        int qty_skip = 0;
        int qty_fail = 0;
        long time_start = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        long time_end = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        m_testIndex = 1;
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            if (suites.size() > 1) {
                titleRow(suite.getName(), 8);
            }
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> tests = suite.getResults();
            for (ISuiteResult r : tests.values()) {
                qty_tests += 1;
                ITestContext overview = r.getTestContext();
                startSummaryRow(overview.getName());
                int q = getMethodSet(overview.getPassedTests(), suite).size();
                qty_pass_m += q;
                summaryCell(q, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                q = overview.getPassedTests().size();
                qty_pass_s += q;
                summaryCell(q, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                q = getMethodSet(overview.getSkippedTests(), suite).size();
                qty_skip += q;
                summaryCell(q, 0);
                q = getMethodSet(overview.getFailedTests(), suite).size();
                qty_fail += q;
                summaryCell(q, 0);

                // NEW
                // Insert error found
                m_out.print("<td class=\"numi" + (true ? "" : "_attn") + "\">");
                getShortException(overview.getFailedTests());
                getShortException(overview.getSkippedTests());
                m_out.println("</td>");

                // NEW
                // Add parameters for each test case (failed or passed)
                m_out.print("<td class=\"numi" + (true ? "" : "_attn") + "\">");

                // Write OS and Browser
                // m_out.println(suite.getParameter("os").substring(0, 3) +
                // " | "
                // + suite.getParameter("browser").substring(0, 3) + " | ");

                getParameters(overview.getFailedTests());
                getParameters(overview.getPassedTests());
                getParameters(overview.getSkippedTests());
                m_out.println("</td>");

                // NEW
                summaryCell(
                        DateFunctions.dateToDayAndTime(overview.getStartDate()),
                        true);
                m_out.println("</td>");
                summaryCell(
                        DateFunctions.dateToDayAndTime(overview.getEndDate()),
                        true);
                m_out.println("</td>");

                time_start = Math.min(overview.getStartDate().getTime(),
                        time_start);
                time_end = Math.max(overview.getEndDate().getTime(), time_end);
                summaryCell(
                        formatter.format((overview.getEndDate().getTime() - overview
                                .getStartDate().getTime()) / 1000.)
                                + " seconds", true);
                summaryCell(overview.getIncludedGroups());
                summaryCell(overview.getExcludedGroups());
                m_out.println("</tr>");
                m_testIndex++;
            }
        }
        if (qty_tests > 1) {
            m_out.println("<tr class=\"total\"><td>Total</td>");
            summaryCell(qty_pass_m, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            summaryCell(qty_pass_s, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            summaryCell(qty_skip, 0);
            summaryCell(qty_fail, 0);
            summaryCell(" ", true);
            summaryCell(" ", true);
            summaryCell(" ", true);
            summaryCell(" ", true);
            summaryCell(
                    formatter.format(((time_end - time_start) / 1000.) / 60.)
                            + " minutes", true);
            m_out.println("<td colspan=\"3\">&nbsp;</td></tr>");
        }
        m_out.println("</table>");
    }

    private void summaryCell(String[] val) {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        for (String v : val) {
            b.append(v + " ");
        }
        summaryCell(b.toString(), true);
    }

    private void summaryCell(String v, boolean isgood) {
        m_out.print("<td class=\"numi" + (isgood ? "" : "_attn") + "\">" + v
                + "</td>");
    }

    private void startSummaryRow(String label) {
        m_row += 1;
        m_out.print("<tr"
                + (m_row % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"stripe\"" : "")
                + "><td style=\"text-align:left;padding-right:2em\"><a href=\"#t"
                + m_testIndex + "\">" + label + "</a>" + "</td>");
    }

    private void summaryCell(int v, int maxexpected) {
        summaryCell(String.valueOf(v), v <= maxexpected);
    }

    private void tableStart(String cssclass, String id) {
        m_out.println("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\""
                + (cssclass != null ? " class=\"" + cssclass + "\""
                        : " style=\"padding-bottom:2em\"")
                + (id != null ? " id=\"" + id + "\"" : "") + ">");
        m_row = 0;
    }

    private void tableColumnStart(String label) {
        m_out.print("<th>" + label + "</th>");
    }

    private void titleRow(String label, int cq) {
        titleRow(label, cq, null);
    }

    private void titleRow(String label, int cq, String id) {
        m_out.print("<tr");
        if (id != null) {
            m_out.print(" id=\"" + id + "\"");
        }
        m_out.println("><th colspan=\"" + cq + "\">" + label + "</th></tr>");
        m_row = 0;
    }

    /** Starts HTML stream */
    protected void startHtml(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">");
        out.println("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hector Flores - TestNG Report</title>");
        out.println("<style type=\"text/css\">");
        out.println("table {margin-bottom:10px;border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells:show}");
        out.println("td,th {border:1px solid #009;padding:.25em .5em}");
        out.println(".result th {vertical-align:bottom}");
        out.println(".param th {padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em}");
        out.println(".param td {padding-left:.5em;padding-right:2em}");
        out.println(".stripe td,.stripe th {background-color: #E6EBF9}");
        out.println(".numi,.numi_attn {text-align:right}");
        out.println(".total td {font-weight:bold}");
        out.println(".passedodd td {background-color: #0A0}");
        out.println(".passedeven td {background-color: #3F3}");
        out.println(".skippedodd td {background-color: #CCC}");
        out.println(".skippedodd td {background-color: #DDD}");
        out.println(".failedodd td,.numi_attn {background-color: #F33}");
        out.println(".failedeven td,.stripe .numi_attn {background-color: #D00}");
        out.println(".stacktrace {white-space:pre;font-family:monospace}");
        out.println(".totop {font-size:85%;text-align:center;border-bottom:2px solid #000}");
        out.println("</style>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
    }

    /** Finishes HTML stream */
    protected void endHtml(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("<center> Report customized by Hector Flores [hectorfb@gmail.com] </center>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    // ~ Inner Classes --------------------------------------------------------
    /** Arranges methods by classname and method name */
    private class TestSorter implements Comparator<IInvokedMethod> {
        // ~ Methods
        // -------------------------------------------------------------

        /** Arranges methods by classname and method name */
        @Override
        public int compare(IInvokedMethod o1, IInvokedMethod o2) {
            // System.out.println("Comparing " + o1.getMethodName() + " " +
            // o1.getDate()
            // + " and " + o2.getMethodName() + " " + o2.getDate());
            return (int) (o1.getDate() - o2.getDate());
            // int r = ((T) o1).getTestClass().getName().compareTo(((T)
            // o2).getTestClass().getName());
            // if (r == 0) {
            // r = ((T) o1).getMethodName().compareTo(((T) o2).getMethodName());
            // }
            // return r;
        }
    }
}
```

With those steps you already have your listener ready to listen.

**How to call it?**

If you use testng.xml add the following lines:

```
 <listeners>
         <listener class-name='[your_class_path].MyReporterListener'/>
 </listeners>
```

If you run your tests from a java class, add the following lines:

```
private final static MyReporterListener frl = new MyReporterListener();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.addListener(frl);
```

With those steps, when you execute your tests you'll have two emailable reports, customized and original.

Now it's time to pimp your report.

In my case I had to add error messages, parameters and times (start and end), because it's very useful if you want to paste on an excel file.

My customized report:

[image: My report]

You have to mainly modify generateSuiteSummaryReport(List suites) function.

Play with that and ask me if you have any problem.

Comment: "Copy ReporterListenerAdapter.java and rename as MyReporterListenerAdapter.java", "copy ReporterListener.java and rename as MyReporterListener.java" -  Where can i find these files?

Comment: Well you can find those classes on testng-X.X.X.jar, call TestNG class from your Eclipse IDE and attach source from your .jar file.
But Ok, copy my code. See next answer.

Comment: There are no classes with these names. Nonetheless, i was able to customize the report based on your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a you CSS and embed it in EmailableReporter.class. This class file can be found in TestNG folder> org.testNg.reporters> EmailableReporter.class.

There you can edit the Style of the TestNG report HTML file which starts with

```
protected void startHtml(PrintWriter out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use extent report html reporting library jar file. However i am using extentreport1.4.jar jar file. So you will get summary details at right corner of your report

Answer (score 0):

Using the above code, I am facing the below null pointer issue, HTML report works fine when fewer tests are included in testng.xml, but when I include more tests, the HTML report does not get generated and the below exception is thrown

```
[TestNG] Reporter report.MyListener@60e07aed failed
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
    at java.base/java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:766)
    at report.MyListener.getShortException(MyListener.java:294)
    at report.MyListener.generateSuiteSummaryReport(MyListener.java:473)
    at report.MyListener.generateReport(MyListener.java:72)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1093)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HnYu.png]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above added a null check to avoid Null Pointer at line 295

```
if(str!=null) {
                   scanner = new Scanner(str);
                   String firstLine = scanner.nextLine()+"<br>";
                   m_out.println(firstLine);
               }
```