# How to append a custom test result into the TestNG emailable-report?

Tags: selenium, testng, test-reporting

I'm creating a custom testNG email-report by implements IReporter listener
but I couldn't find a way to pass a custom string such as brower type to the emailable-report...

for exmaple, the default emailable-report is like this:

```
Test    Methods Passed  Scenarios  Passed   # skipped   # failed
atestname      0    0   0      1             1                   1
```

My Question is how to add a custom value after the last column, for example, I would like to add the brower name like "ie","firefox" etc.

seems I need to pass the custom browser name to some parameter or attribute when I create my webDriver and this parameter should be able to be read from the test result? Is it correct? And how to do this?

Comment: Seems like there is already an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585036/2724688) for your question.


  [1]: