# Test NG - Add description in html generated files

Tags: webdriver, testng

I'm using testng, testers asked me if it possible to add test description into test results ( email and index).

I have checked the solution but I did not found and proper solution. In `index.html` steps are displayed, but in `emailable-report.html` are not. I would like to have`@description` displayed in `emailable-report.html`.

Does anyone have solution to my problem or what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Customize testng report by using testng Listeners

Detailed instruction to customize emailable reports is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564862/customizing-summary-section-of-testng-emailable-report)

Comment: Thank you for help, meanwhile i found this instructions, i was able to solve my issue.

Comment: dude if you've found a solution you should post it back to your own post