# TestNG Customized Emailable report not showing all the Test Methods of the Same Class Together

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

We have implemented Customized Emailable report with reference to [Customizing summary section of TestNG emailable report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564862/customizing-summary-section-of-testng-emailable-report).
Default emailable report is showing all tests methods of a class together. But customized Emailable report is not showing the same. Please look at the below sample reports.

**Default Emailable Report Output**

com.pack.sampleOne

- testcaseLogin
- testCaseForgotpassword

com.pack.sampleTwo

- testCaseChangePassword
- testCaseHomePage
- testCaseManageProfile

**Customized Emailable Report Output**

com.pack.sampleOne

- testcaseLogin

com.pack.sampleTwo

- testCaseHomePage
- testCaseChangePassword

com.pack.sampleOne

- testCaseForgotpassword

com.pack.sampleTwo

- testCaseManageProfile

How can we display all the tests methods of the same class together as default emailable report in customized emailable report.

Comment: Can we have the code of your customized report?

Comment: Please see the link that i have linked in my question.

Comment: @VivekSingh Can any one please help. There is a method with `public int compare(IInvokedMethod o1, IInvokedMethod o2) { }`' . Can we do any thing here.  I tried the code which is mentioned there. But i am getting exception `java.lang.ClassCastException'.