# Customize TestNG Report

Tags: testng

I have a request regarding TestNG reports coming from a client.  I am currently doing a multi browser test and I have the index.html in test-output and also the browser specific tests (the ones with the bright colored background, green = pass and red - fail).

The client is requesting a change to the browser specific tests.  He wants the  color of the failed tests to be changed from bright red to a darker red.  Any idea how you do this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own Listener. I found a very good answer for about a similar question: [Customizing summary section of TestNG emailable report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564862/customizing-summary-section-of-testng-emailable-report)

Or you can parse the **testng-results.xml** in the test-output directory, and insert the datas in your custom layout. We are doing the same using PHP.