# How to customize TestNG Email-able HTML report to include data from the test executed?

Tags: testng, reporting

Am looking if there is a possibility to customise the TestNG Email-able report to include data from the test executed. For example, I have a Test Method which creates a unique id whenever the Test is run. Now I would like to include the unique id in the report in a new column. I am new to TestNG and have searched this topic but did not come across anywhere. I understand that there are Listeners that can be implemented to customise the reports which can include data like Test Start time, end time, execution time etc. However am interested to include details from response of the test executed, like unique id generated, error code/message from the response instead of stack trace etc.. Any help is appreciated.!

[Sample TestNG Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gYdS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement `IReporter` and then change the `createWriter` function. I think your question is exactly what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564862/customizing-summary-section-of-testng-emailable-report) . You may have to change other things that are needed specifically to your need but the concept is exactly same.

Also look [here](http://djangofan.github.io/testng-custom-report-example/) for complete working example, its from the same above link.

You can also take a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309879/how-dataprovider-publish-the-test-data-into-html-report/47426325#47426325), where I answered on how to implement a custom [`TestHTMLReporter`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TestHTMLReporter.java)